Bend paper maintaning proportions / rig constraints
I'm trying to animate an 8 page booklet from an A4 sheet. I have no problem assigning bones to each individual page but I can't seem to create a rig system that stays consistent with the natural motion of the object (example video).
The closest I've gotten, however, doesn't keep the pages indicated by the arrows properly aligned/constrained. However I can't get the bones to move in a consistent and valid way, I have set the limits in the right directions but the bones don't seem to bend, or at least they only do so in one point.
I've tried searching for information but I can't figure out what solution/approach I can adopt.
I see that also Geometry nodes could work for this but never used them.



Edit: Not sure it anwsers your question. A little bit tedious but you could parent the mesh this way, each bone controlling the 2 adjacent vertices:

Once animated:

File: 

This seems perfect for my case, i see just some overlapping in the last fold but something i think i could manage, i'll try to replicate it. Thank you a lot.

Yes i didn't try to make it precise but it should work

Your approach is different from what I had thought, I'm having trouble understanding if there is a particular hierarchy of bones or if you used some particular constraint. When you raise the center how do you make the external bones "follow"? when you bend the central cross how do you manage to perform the mirror movement? because then the central pairs move away

there's just a root bone and all the other bones are parented to this root, here is the file: 

I don't make the external bones follow, I just move them, of course you'll have to make sure that the length of the face is always about the same

Thank you for the answer, It could work as a workaround but I would like to better learn about bone constraints and how to organize the workflow

the animation is rather complicated so I'm not sure that there's any solution other than the kind of trick i've used
